# Batch File not working and it again and again prompts for user input

Tags: batch-file

Below is the script.I am copying files based on date given by user.

```
@echo off
echo Enter Date in mm-dd-yyyy:
set /p dt= 
echo %dt%

if %dt% =="" goto :EnterDate


if not %dt% =="" goto :CopyFile

:CopyFile
xcopy C:\Users\hkum29\Desktop\Source\*.* C:\Users\hkum29\Desktop\Destination\*.* /d:%dt%

:EnterDate
echo Enter Date

Pause
```

Comment: `if "%dt%" == "" goto :EnterDate` and don't need the second if

Answer (score 1):

`IF` syntax is `if string1 operator string2 action`

If `string1` or `string2` is "quoted" (which allows a string to contain spaces) then **BOTH** strings must be quoted.

Batch has no concept of "sections", "functions", "procedures" or "paragraphs". A label is simply a reference point. Execution does not stop when a label is reached, it simply continues through, line by line, until it reaches end-of-file, a **CALL** , a **GOTO** or an **EXIT**

Answer (score 0):

Think that Script logic should be

```
@echo off 
SetLocal
:EnterDate
set /p dt="Enter Date in mm-dd-yyyy: " 
if "%dt%" == "" goto :EnterDate

:CopyFile
echo %dt%
xcopy C:\Users\hkum29\Desktop\Source\*.* C:\Users\hkum29\Desktop\Destination\*.* /d:%dt%
EndLocal
Pause
```

You should better add date validation [Batch Script: Validate Date Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414027/batch-script-validate-date-input/20415739#20415739)

You may also validate it using a very ugly trick, (for it **ab**uses the system date)

```
@echo off 
SetLocal
:EnterDate
set /p dt="Enter Date in mm-dd-yyyy: " 
if "%dt%" == "" goto :EnterDate

set "saved_date=%date%"
echo %dt%|DATE >NUL 2>&1 && (
  echo %saved_date%|DATE >NUL 2>&1
) || (
  echo %saved_date%|DATE >NUL 2>&1 
  echo %dt% is not a valid date
  goto :EnterDate
)

:CopyFile
echo %dt%
echo xcopy C:\Users\hkum29\Desktop\Source\*.* C:\Users\hkum29\Desktop\Destination\*.* /d:%dt%
EndLocal
Pause

exit/B
```

Comment: Using `mm-dd-yyyy` only works on systems in locales such as en_US. Using `robocopy` might be a better choice.